Performance Degradation in Aws Spot Instances while running the same process on multiple cores
Problem : I am observing a performance degradation of over 100 % when I am running the same program on all the cores of Aws spot instance by pinning them on separate cores in comparison to running a single program by pinning it to a single core.
Observation : While running the program given below on instance type m7i.8xlarge of Aws spot instances by pinning on a single core I observe a execution time of 17 seconds whereas when I run the same program by pinning on all 16 cores I observe an average execution time of 35 seconds. In my setup I have disabled hyperthreading. Also I have seen such a similar degradation in other Aws spot instances such as m7a.8xlarge, m6i.8xlarge, m6a.8xlarge, c7i.8xlarge, c7a.8xlarge, c6i.8xlarge, c6a.8xlarge, r7i.8xlarge, r7a.8xlarge, r6i.8xlarge, r6a8xlarge. Why I am seeing such a degradation in performance over Aws spot instances when I run the same process on all cores by pinning them in comparison to a single process running by pinning on a single core.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 1500

void initialize_matrix(double **matrix) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) 
    {
            matrix[i][j] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX; 
        }
    }
}

void multiply_matrices(double **a, double **b, double **result) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) 
    {
            result[i][j] = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) 
        {
                result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    double **a = (double **)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double *));
    double **b = (double **)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double *));
    double **result = (double **)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double *));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = (double *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double));
        b[i] = (double *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double));
        result[i] = (double *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double));
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    initialize_matrix(a);
    initialize_matrix(b);

    clock_t start = clock();

    multiply_matrices(a, b, result);

    clock_t end = clock();

    double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken for matrix multiplication: %f seconds\n", time_taken);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        free(a[i]);
        free(b[i]);
        free(result[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}


On my local machine also with hyperthreading disabled, I have run this program on all cores by pinning them on separate cores and I have observed a maximum degradation of 20% but here in Aws spot instances the degradation is over 100 % and I am unable to figure out the reasoning behind this. Can someone help me with a fix to reduce this degradation or give me a possible reason for this degradation.

Side-note: The concept of a 'Spot Instance' only impacts billing and the possibility that the instance will be terminated if there is insufficient capacity. It would not impact the performance or behaviour of the instance itself.
